# Mockito verify post object has same values not same object reference

Tags: spring-mvc, mockito

This is my test:

```
    @Test
    public void shouldProcessRegistration() throws Exception {
        Spitter unsaved = new Spitter("Gustavo", "Diaz", "gdiaz", "gd123");
        Spitter saved = new Spitter(24L, "Gustavo", "Diaz", "gdiaz", "gd123");
        SpitterRepository spittlerRepository = Mockito.mock(SpitterRepository.class);
        Mockito.when(spittlerRepository.save(unsaved)).thenReturn(saved);

        SpitterController spittleController = new SpitterController(spittlerRepository);

        MockMvc mockSpittleController = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(spittleController).build();

        mockSpittleController.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/spitter/register")
                .param("firstName", "Gustavo")
                .param("lastName", "Diaz")
                .param("userName", "gdiaz")
                .param("password", "gd123"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.redirectedUrl("/spitter/" + saved.getUserName()));

        Mockito.verify(spittlerRepository, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).save(unsaved);
    }
```

This is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "spitter")
public class SpitterController {
    SpitterRepository spitterRepository;

    @Autowired
    public SpitterController(SpitterRepository spittlerRepository) {
        this.spitterRepository = spittlerRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processRegistration(Spitter spitter){
        spitterRepository.save(spitter);

        return "redirect:/spitter/" + spitter.getUserName();
    }
}
```

I want to verify that `spitterRepository.save` was called passing the same `unsaved` object I defined in the test. But i'm getting this exception:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
spitterRepository.save(
    spittr.Spitter@3bd82cf5
);
-> at spitter.controllers.test.SpitterControllerTest.shouldProcessRegistration(SpitterControllerTest.java:48)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
spitterRepository.save(
    spittr.Spitter@544fa968
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an `ArgumentCaptor` to capture the value passed to save, and then assert on it.

```
ArgumentCaptor<Spitter> spitterArgument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Spitter.class);
verify(spittlerRepository, atLeastOnce()).save(spitterArgument.capture());

assertEquals("Gustavo", spitterArgument.getValue().getName());
```

For asserting if the Bean is the same, I would recommend you to use Hamcrest's samePropertyValues (http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/beans/SamePropertyValuesAs.html)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the below line initializes a mock where you can utilize the capabilities in Spring.

```
MockMvc mockSpittleController = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(spittleController).build();
```

When you call the mock like below, you will not call the method with the `unsaved` object. Rather, I guess a new object will be created.

```
mockSpittleController.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/spitter/register")
          .param("firstName", "Gustavo")
          .param("lastName", "Diaz")
          .param("userName", "gdiaz")
          .param("password", "gd123"))
          .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.redirectedUrl("/spitter/" + saved.getUserName()));
```

This makes the verification fail, because the instances will not be the same.

To solve this, you should make sure that `Spitter` implements `equals()` and then use the [`eq()`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Matchers.html#eq(T)) matcher for the verification:

```
Mockito.verify(spittlerRepository, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).save(org.mockito.Matchers.eq(unsaved));
```

This will check if the expected argument `equals()` what was passed.

Comment: I call the mock like that because I'm simulating a form submission. Isn't there another way to compare the values?, because overriding the equals method modify my class behaivor just to accomplish one assert.

Comment: In that case, you should go with the solution proposed by @Ruben.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.mockito.Matchers;
//...
Mockito.verify(spittlerRepository, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).save(Matchers.refEq(unsaved));
```